# BIRT report viewer localization

Tags: birt

I'm using Birt web report viewer 4.2.1 , and how can I localize report viewer language to Russian, Localization offered by eclipse site only for certain IDE,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the Spanish language. I solved it by downloading the package for "Helios" from "http://www.eclipse.org/babel/downloads.php".

For the Russian language:

1. download http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.10.1/helios/BabelLanguagePack-birt-ru_3.6.0.v20121120125106.zip
2. unzip
3. copy "org.eclipse.birt.resources.nl_ru_3.6.0.v20121120125106.jar" WEB-INF/lib directory of your BIRT viewer installation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for information. I will use this, but actually I found another solution that I've downloaded "https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=118129" this and replaced "viewservlets.jar/org\eclipse\birt\report\resource\Messages.properties" this file with it.